# Changing styles of Font icons

Tags: angular8, angular9

I want to change width, height and rotate the square. I tried giving styles using inline styling but it is not working. My code is as follows:

```html
component.ts:
import { faSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

 faSquare =faSquare;

html:

<fa-icon [icon]="faSquare"</fa-icon>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide inline styles to inside the icon as given below:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faSquare" [styles]="{height: '40px', width: '40px', transform: 'rotate(25deg)'}"></fa-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
component.ts:
import { faSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

 faSquare =faSquare;

html:

<fa-icon [icon]="faSquare"</fa-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
component.ts:
import { faSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

faSquare =faSquare;

html:

<fa-icon [icon]="faSquare" [styles]="

#change width, height
{height: '64px', width: '64px', 

#rotate square
transform: 'rotate(30deg)'}">

</fa-icon>
```